# Who voiced the Enterprise computer in "Encounter at Farpoint"?

Tags: credits, star-trek-the-next-generation, voice-acting

It doesn't sound like [Majel Barrett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majel_Barrett) to me, and she isn't credited. [Memory Alpha says,](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Computer_voice)

> [Majel Barrett] continued the role on Star Trek: The Next Generation (with the exception of some early episodes), ...

The [IMDB cast page](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0094030/fullcredits/cast?ref_=m_ttfc_3) for the episode doesn't list any voice actor.

The computer voice can be heard when Riker gets directions to the holodeck. Whose voice is it?

Comment: I'm not a mod, but a question being on topic for one SE doesn't make it off topic for every other one. It being out-of-universe does make it somewhat more on topic here, but I don't think it would be off topic in SFF.

Comment: As to what is on/off-topic, you can visit the Help Center for the particular SE in question. If you are still not sure, you could also ask in the Meta for the particular SE.

Comment: @Acccumulation indeed, this question would be on-topic on SFF Stack Exchange under the [behind-the-scenes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behind-the-scenes) or [actors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actors) tags, but is certainly on-topic here too.

Comment: Thanks all - I have deleted the P.S. asking for OT advice from the question. Appreciate the guidance!

Comment: Memory Alpha's page for the episode lists the computer voice as an "unknown performer." If they can't find the information, you're going to need someone with access to people involved in the production (and hope they can recall).